# Protractor Unable to click on the button even though it finds it

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been struggling to click on a button using Protractor.The problem is that even that the driver finds the element but it still doesn't click it.Any Help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Below is the HTML for the Sign in Button:

```html
div class="row mod-form-button">
                <button id="sign_in" class="mod-main" tabindex="4">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                    <span class="nowrap">Not a member yet?</span>
                    <a class="nowrap" data-component="spinner" id="create_account"
                       href="create_account?client_id=UDPWeb1&callback=https%3A%2F%2F-na1-stg1.login.com">
                        Get an Test ID</a>
                </div>
```

Protractor Code:
This is the specs file:
// spec.js

```
    describe(' Demo', function() {

  it('Should Login to Demo Site', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('https://stage.com');



   // var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
//browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('password')), 5000);
    element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('123456');
    element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Tester@test.com');
    //browser.sleep(35000);

     var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
 element(by.id('sign_in')).click();
 browser.sleep(5000);
 var el = element(by.id('sign_in'));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', el.getWebElement());

el.click();
// browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('sign_in')), 5000);
//browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('.btn.coral-btn.coral-btn-primary')), 5000);
//element(by.css('.btn.coral-btn.coral-btn-primary')).click();
  //  expect(element(by.binding('latest')).getText()).
      //  toEqual('5'); // This is wrong!
  });
});
```

This is the config file:
//Config.js

```
exports.config = {

  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   allScriptsTimeout: 5000000,
  specs: ['specs.js']


}
```

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, can you please let me know how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

i had exp only with Selenium-java, and test front-end with it.
The steps i used to test thinks like yours.

Use click button, after check that exist. (sometimes click evt() works early than check).So when it try to click on button, button doesn't exist yet.

In your case i will do this steps:

1. Use ExpectedCondition to check that page has been already loaded.
   ExpectedConditions.until(visibilityOf(WebElement)). push element
   like input (log or pass).
2. SendKeys for inputs. Than you can check input.value
3. Button click check, that is exist and clickable.
4. by.id(btnID).click().

I hope it will helps.

Comment: Thanks Taras,I have already used the above solution and it doesn't work.Also the element is present or else it would have given and element not present exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confused, you actually declare the `protractor.ExpectedConditions` but you never use it in the proper way.

Then be careful because all the protractor methods return promises, because all the operations are asynchronous. You should use promises properly.

By the way, try this code it should wait for the element to be visible and then click on it:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var signinButton = element(by.id('sign_in'));
// waiting for 10 seconds that the button will be visible
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(signinButton ), 10000, "Button signin not visible");
    browser.executeScript('document.querySelector("#sign_in").scrollIntoView()').then(function() {
  signinButton.click().then(function() {
    console.log('button has been clicked here');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but its doesn't work either:`[17:14:08] E/launcher - Error: /Users/rtripath/Documents/protactor/specs.js:23
    browser.executeScript('document.getElementByXpath('#sign_in').scrollIntoView()').then(function() {
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: sorry I concatenated quotes bad, please check my current edit

Comment: Thanks for the help @quirimmo. But this still doesn't help.It has the same problem.it just skips the click and passes.See the image on the link below:https://ibb.co/f1hjca

Comment: But the element is correctly retrieved? Are you sure it is not clicked? Try to add an alert inside the click code and see if the alert is triggered. Manage also as promises the send keys methods inside the tests. They return promises

Comment: Yes the element is correctly retrieved or else i would have got an exception.I am sure that its not clicked as I have added an explicit wait and if it was clicked it should have gone to the next page.